# How can I configure triggers for Auto Scaling EC2 instances in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: triggers, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

I would like to configure triggers for Auto Scaling in Elastic Beanstalk.

Basically I want to scale-out new instance if the user does not get response for more than 4 seconds.

Can you please advise how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Elastic Beanstalk, you can set triggers which will start new instances, if users don't get responses in the specified time. While configuring your environment in Elastic Beanstalk, you can setup an EC2 instance health check and configure the health check interval and health check timeout. If the server doesn't respond within the health check interval, Auto Scaling will bring up new instances.

For more details: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/ug/index.html?using-features.managing.elb.html

Answer (score 3):

AWS EB has a specific scaling metric for latency, amongst others, which is what you'd want to use in your case. The health check is important as SanketDangi mentioned, but to be clear it won't automatically "bring up new instances". It WILL for sure take that failed instance out of service. As to whether this kicks off a scaling operation, that depends on the auto scaling policies, like the configured Min Instances for example that EB sets up for you when creating a new EB app.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it addresses the true auto-scaling solution. Health check policies will only *replace* the now-unhealthy instance only, but not scale up.